# Bundle loopback using webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, loopbackjs, webpack-4

I am using `"webpack": "^4.43.0"` to bundle my loopback-3 application. I can run webpack command without any problems and it executes, but after running the bundled file I get following error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\cldr'`

Here is `webpack.conf.js` content:

```
const path = require('path');
const LoopbackBootPlugin = require('loopback-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  entry: './server/server.js',
  mode: 'production',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: `bundle.js`,
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new LoopbackBootPlugin()
  ]
};
```

I tried adding

```
alias: {
      cldr$: 'cldrjs',
      cldr: 'cldrjs/dist/cldr'
    }
```

to resolve property but still not working right.

Answer (score 0):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

LoopBack does not support bundling via Webpack, only [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) is supported.

At startup, LoopBack is loading files using dynamic paths, therefore it needs custom integration with bundlers to ensure dynamically loaded artifacts are included in the browser bundle and can be loaded by loopback-boot.

Cross-posting from https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-Browserify.html:

> The build step loads all configuration files, merges values from additional config files like `app.local.js` and produces a set of instructions that can be used to boot the application.
>
> These instructions must be included in the browser bundle together with all configuration scripts from `models/` and `boot/`.
>
> Don't worry, you don't have to understand these details. Just call `boot.compileToBrowserify()`, and it will take care of everything for you.

```js
var browserify = require('browserify');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var b = browserify({
  basedir: appDir,
});

// add the main application file
b.require('./browser-app.js', { expose: 'loopback-app' });

// add boot instructions
boot.compileToBrowserify(appDir, b);

// create the bundle
var out = fs.createWriteStream('browser-bundle.js');
b.bundle().pipe(out);
// handle out.on('error') and out.on('close')
```

You can find the source for `compileToBrowserify` here in [`loopback-boot/lib/bundler.js`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-boot/blob/56dcfaab6c20ba1c1269258a9baafd4c80ca0494/lib/bundler.js). I think it should be possible to adapt the script to use Webpack instead of Browserify APIs, but I have never tried that, so YMMV ‍♂️